# Silverlight TransitioningContentControl Issue

Tags: .net, silverlight-3.0

We're trying to use TransitioningContentControl of Silverlight toolkit in our application.

Almost all the material on the forum shows how to change content of the same control inside the TransitionContentControl.

I have 2 separate grids, Grid1 & Grid 2 on the page and i need to transition each of them.
On the click of a hyperlink button in Grid1 I need to show Grid2 and vice versa.
Is there any way to achieve this. Here is the code snippet for reference:

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I´m not quite shure but I doubt.The Toolkit you refer to runs against the content property of a usercontrol. For a DataGrid has a Datasource /or Itemsource it´ll not support this transition.
Best way would be do make Copy of your Datasource, make a double animation for the fadeout and fade in, add the Grid withe viso-ve Source Opacity = 0 in the same conatiner and remove the useless at animation end event ...